# How to plot the mean by group in a boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot, box

I can't manage to draw the mean in the corresponding box. The green dot and the "4" have to appear in "B". In addition, the right axis does not show all the decimals, while the left axis shows both decimals. How can I correct both errors?
[image]

[image]

```
boxplot(x,y,  ylab="Puntos",axes = FALSE)
points(mean(x), col = 3, pch = 19)
points(mean(y), col = 3, pch = 19)
text(t, labels=c(r),cex = 1.2, pos = 3, col = "red")
text(t1, labels=c(r1),cex = 1.2, pos = 3, col = "red")
axis(side = 1, at = c(1,2), labels = c("A","B"))
axis(side =2, at = signif(b$stats,3), las = 1)
axis(side =4, at = signif(b1$stats,3), las = 1)
box()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using ggplot for such plots, here is a solution using ggplot2, tidyr and dplyr.

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)*2+4

df = data.frame(x=x, y=y)
df_stats = data.frame(x=mean(df$x), y=mean(df$y))

df_stats <- df_stats %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(cols=c("x", "y")) 
df <- df %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(cols=c("x", "y")) 

ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(df, mapping=aes(y=value)) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales="free_y", dir="h") +
  geom_point(df_stats, mapping=aes(x=0., y=value, color="red"), show.legend=F) +
  geom_text(df_stats, mapping=aes(x=0, y=value, label=round(value, 2)),
            vjust = -2.0) +
  xlab(" ") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to stick to plot from base, points(c(mean(x), mean(y)), col = 3, pch = 19) will solve your green point problem.

Comment: Yes, the green dot is solved, but not the mean value. I have added the graph of how it would look with "points(c(mean(x), mean(y)), col = 3, pch = 19)".

Comment: Following your idea, I have solved it as shown above. But, how can I put the two graphs in parallel?

Comment: Now it is perfect with "par(mfrow = c(1, 2))".